# How to display dynamic text in magento static block depending on time and day of week?

Tags: javascript, magento

In a static block in magento I want to display a dynamic message depending on the day of the week and the time.

It's for customers, so they know when customer support is open and when it is closed.

For example: I want to display: "Now Open" on monday - fridays from 09:00 till 17:00. 
On saturday, sunday and on monday - friday from 17:01 untill 08:59 I want to display the text: "Now closed".

Is there a way to do this with javascript or any other way?

Please keep in mind that I'm quite a noob on this matter :).

All help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't provided the complete solution here because it will take certain time and effort but i could help you with some idea, so that you can achieve your requirement.

The logic is :

1. You can create two static block with the image or info for **open** and 
   **close**.You can easily do it from admin panel.
2. Now the main portion.i.e. you need to manipulate time and days.If you want it fully dynamic and if the admin could choose the days and time than you need to create a custom module. In that module you need to provide a place to choose the days and time(You have to use your logic here,How it will be easier for you to manipulate the data you get from here.  You can use multi-select for days and so on).
3. Next part is,after after your module is ready you have to get that data inserted from the backend to the template file where you want to display the static blocks.There you have to use some conditions to show either the **open** or **close** block.

You may need to do little research on how to manipulate time in your case. That's all.

Try this, if you have any further problems than feel free to ask.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to came up with another solution.

Place this in HTML Head:

```
<style type="text/css">
#openSign.OPEN {
color: green;
background-color: yellow;
font-size: x-large;
}
#openSign.CLOSED {
color : red;
background-color: pink;
font-size: large;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

var OPENAT = 7.5; // 7:30 AM ... change as appropriate - can be fractions of an hour e.g. 7.5 = 7:30am
var CLOSEAT = 21; // 9:00 PM ... change as appropriate

function areWeOpen( ) {
var sign = document.getElementById("openSign");
var day = new Date().getDay();
var hour = new Date().getHours();
var mins = new Date().getMinutes();
hour = hour + mins/60;
if ( day >=1 && day <=5 && hour >= OPENAT && hour < CLOSEAT )  {
sign.innerHTML = "We are now OPEN";
sign.className = "OPEN";
} 
else {
sign.innerHTML = "Sorry, we are now CLOSED";
sign.className = "CLOSED";
}
}
</script>
```

And this in the static block:

```
<body onload = "areWeOpen()">
<span id="openSign"></span>
```

I don't know if this is a neat solution, but it works for me.